# .env not working with Django with supervisor

Tags: django, environment-variables, supervisord

I have a **Django 2.2** project and all secrets are in **.env** file.

I'm using a library `dotenv` to load `.env` to the Django application in the `manage.py` file

```
import dotenv

def main():

    # Read from .env file
    env_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '.env')
    dotenv.read_dotenv(env_file)
    ....
```

The environment file is working and is loaded well when running locally.

On the server, I'm using the **supervisor** to run the application with the following configuration.

```
[supervisord]
[program:myapp]
command=/var/www/html/app/start_gunicorn.sh
directory=/var/www/html/app/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
logfile=/home/ubuntu/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
logfile_maxbytes=5MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel = info
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/log/supervisor/qcg-backend.err.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/log/supervisor/qcg-backend.out.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

But the environment variables are not loaded and not working in Django.

Running following command from SSH console is working.

```
python manage.py shell
import os
os.environ.get('DEBUG')
> True
```

**But running the application, environment variables are not accessible and not applied in the application.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manage.py` is not invoked when running Django in production. From the [dotenv docs](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#django), it says that you should add the loader code to the top of `wsgi.py` as well.

Comment: but in production also, the Django server is started using the command `python manage.py runserver` which clearly states that the file being executed is `manage.py`.

Comment: No, that is not the proper way to run a Django production server. From the Django docs "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver

Comment: Thanks. I'll change my application deployment accordingly. But at present, the server is run by `manage.py`, shouldn't environment variables work the way it is working in locally (even in debug mode)?

Comment: Why do you think `manage.py runserver` is running on the server? Your supervisor script in your question is running `/var/www/html/app/start_gunicorn.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting it on settings.py is more convenient. No need to add it to both manage.py and wsgi.py